# How can I make ::selection correct in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

CSS `::selection` works incorrect is Safari.

If block with text has some child blocks, selection in parent doesn't work.

For example:

```css
::selection {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Text...
  <div class="child">Text...</div>
</div>
```

In this code text in parent block selected without my styles (only default OS X selection). [Result (screenshot)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n74939gfwvn84a5/Screenshot%202015-02-21%2016.29.59.png?dl=0).

How can I fix this?
Wrapping all content in divs is not the best solution...
I now special rule, but only for FF `::-moz-selection`.
In other browsers code like this works best.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work-around be a solution in your case?
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/GgdRvx

As you can see I've removed the child div and replaced it with a span that tries to imitate a div :)

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
   Parent text...
   <span class="child">Child text...</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
::selection {
  background: #000; 
  color: #fff;}

span.child{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;}
```

It's giving good results for me with Safari 8.0.3

Good luck!